# Python switching multiple positions in string each to multiple letters

Tags: python, string, loops, random, sequence

I am trying to write a python code that finds restriction enzyme sites within a sequence of DNA. Restriction enzymes cut at specific DNA sequences, however some are not so strict, for example XmnI cuts this sequence:

GAANNNNTTC

Where N can be any nucleotide (A, C, G, or T). If my math is right thats 4^4 = 256 unique sequences that it can cut. I want to make a list of these 256 short sequences, then check each one against a (longer) input DNA sequence. However, I'm having a hard time generating the 256 sequences. Here's what I have so far:

```
cutsequencequery = "GAANNNNTTC"
Nseq = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]
querylist = []
if "N" in cutsequencequery:
    Nlist = [cutsequencequery.replace("N", t) for t in Nseq]
    for j in list(Nlist):
        querylist.append(j)

for i in querylist:
    print(i)
print(len(querylist))
```

and here is the output:

```
GAAAAAATTC
GAACCCCTTC
GAAGGGGTTC
GAATTTTTTC
4
```

So it's switching each N to either A, C, G, and T, but I think I need another loop (or 3?) to generate all 256 combinations. Is there an efficient way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: So everytime "N" appears, you want to substitute in every value in `Nseq`

Comment: exactly. switch each N to either A, T, G, or C and generate every combination of the sequences.

Comment: To substitute those `N`'s you would need a `for` loop for every `N` and then substitute them to the next set of possible outcomes of `nseq`. Anyway, I posted (what I think is) a solution using [itertool's product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look into [python's itertools library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which include `product` which creates an iterable with every combination of iterables, therefore:

```py
from itertools import product

cutsequencequery = "GAANNNNTTC"
nseq = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]

size = cutsequencequery.count('N')

possibilities = product(*[nseq for i in range(size)]) 
# = ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ... , ('T', 'T', 'T', 'T') 
# len(list(possibilities)) = 256 = 4^4, as expected

s = set()
for n in possibilities:
    print(''.join(n)) # = 'AAAA', ..., 'TTTT'
    new_sequence = cutsequencequery.replace('N' * size, ''.join(n))
    
    s.add(new_sequence)
    print(new_sequence) # = 'GAAAAAATTC', ..., 'GAATTTTTTC'
print(len(s)) # 256 unique sequences
```

Comment: This worked, did not know about the itertools library. Thank you!